# Change pin node style in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

With pgfplot, how can I change the style of a "pin node" to have a thicker line?

I saw posts here how to change the "text label" part of the pin node.. but not this little line beneath it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: I assume your problem is not specific to pgfplots, but also applies to pure TikZ/PGF? In that case, the question should probably be retagged.

Answer (score 20):

You can use `\tikzset{every pin edge/.style={draw=red, ultra thick}}`, or as @Jake pointed out, you can specify the options for the `pin edge` as:

```
\node [coordinate, pin={[pin edge={red, ultra thick}]foobar}] at (0,0) {};
```

[image]

### Code: `\tikzset{every pin edge/.style={}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{every pin edge/.style={draw=red, ultra thick}}

  \node [coordinate, pin={[ultra thick, draw=blue, fill=yellow]foobar}] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Code: `pin edge` option within `pin=`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [coordinate, pin={[ultra thick, draw=blue, fill=yellow,pin edge={red, ultra thick}]foobar}] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I would like to create a pin that is more thin than `thick`, can I do this? I mean what are the options available for `pin edge`; `ultra thick`, `thick`, and ...? Thank you.

Comment: @Ribz: You should be able to specify the `line width` (or might be one word).